# How to change sitemaster for guest in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, menu

I design one sitemaster in asp.net that has a menu for user, but I want when guest enter to special page the menu doesn’t show.

Comment: Are you using MVC/Razor?

Comment: try to contain that menubar inside `div` or `panel` and just apply a condition based on guest enter , if guest enter set that menu or panel visible proprty to false else true.

Answer (score 1):

You can set master page run time on the specific condition.
There is a Event `Page_PreInit` who will be executing just before 
the page render. 
We have to do code in this event like below

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
 if (Membership.GetUser() == null) //check the user weather user is logged in or not
    this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/General.master";//master page with menu
 else
    this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/myMaster.master";//master page with out menu
}
```

we can change the content of master page from inherited page too like below

```
Master.FindControl("menu").Visible = true;
```

Comment: Ok, but can I add tow master page in my page? (in top of page)
<%@ Page Title=" " Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="a.aspx.cs" Inherits="main_a" %>

Comment: No you can't add two master from designer (.aspx page). You can add default master page there and change it from .cs page in Page_PreInit event.